# auto height image in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

please help;
I tried to set height auto by react-native-auto-height component, but what I've got is so different from what I expected to get.

this is FeedCard.js:

```
const PicsCardContent = styled(Touchable).attrs({
feedback: 'opacity'
})`
 width: ${9*width/28};
 borderWidth: 1;
 borderColor: ${props => props.theme.WHITE};
 backgroundColor: ${props => props.theme.WHITE};
 marginBottom: 10;
 borderRadius: 4;
`

function FeedCard({ user }) {
  return(
    <Root>
      <PicsCardContent>
        <AutoHeightImage  width={9*width/28} imageURL={ user.image }/>
      </PicsCardContent>
    </Root>
  );
}
```

and this is HomeScreen.js:

```
class HomeScreen extends Component {

_renderItem = ({ item }) => <FeedCard {...item} />

return (
  <Root>
    <FlatList
      contentContainerStyle={{ alignSelf: 'stretch'}}
      data={data.getPosts}
      keyExtractor={item => item._id}
      renderItem={this._renderItem}
      numColumns={3}
    />
  </Root>
 );
}
}
```

I attached the screenshot below; 
thanks for helps.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyiXi.png)

Comment: Use `flex` https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/height-and-width.html

Comment: I tried, and still have the same issue.